# Confusion with __init__.py and importing classes in parent module from submodule

Tags: python, initialization, package

I'm having a little difficulty understanding how to import classes from a parent module from within a submodule. I have the following directory structure:

```
   module/
      __init__.py        (1)
      common.py          (containing testfunc and CommonClass)
      submod/
         __init__.py     (2)
         test.py         (containing TestClass)
```

in `(1)` I have:

```
   from common import *
```

So I can do directly:

```
   import module
   module.testfunc()
```

in `(2)` I have:

```
   from test import TestClass
```

So from within `module` I can do:

```
   import submod
   class_inst = submod.TestClass()
```

Now in `TestClass` (contained in `test.py`) I want to use an instance of `CommonClass`, so I tried first importing it using:

```
   from ..common import *
```

Which works fine, but when I try to create an instance of `CommonClass` in `TestClass`:

```
   class TestClass(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self.inst = CommonClass()
```

I get the error:

```
   NameError: global name 'CommonClass' is not defined
```

Similarly if I try instead `from ..common import CommonClass` I get the error:

```
   ImportError: cannot import name CommonClass
```

As far as I can tell, `CommonClass` should be visible from within `test.py`, so I'm not sure why it can't be found. I have a feeling there is something I'm not understanding about the usage of `__init__.py`. Is there anyone who can help by pointing out any obvious mistakes I am making?

Comment: Did you mean `submod` where you wrote `engine` and `engines`?

Comment: Yes – sorry, have updated the question :)

Comment: Some rules of thumb to avoid confusion: Don't put anything in `__init__.py` files, except possibly the top-level one. Don't have module-level code do anything besides define objects and factory functions, and constant data. These problems occur because the modules may not be fully initialized or imported when you use it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, I'm not sure how better to structure the code. I have a bunch of classes in `submod` that all fulfil a similar but slightly different role, and want to use a 'common' class in `module` to execute the shared part. This doesn't seem like it should cause a problem as a design pattern, but am open to suggestions on how it could be improved. Regardless, it would also be interesting to understand why the above is not working, as I have a feeling it would help me to gain a deeper understanding of `__init__.py` files and their workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to say "circular imports" but I can't quite pinpoint it. The ImportError you're seeing might well be a symptom of that. Generally, if you import a module which in turn imports something else, and the import chain ends up importing the very module that started all the importing, you'll get an ImportError.

Can you move `CommonClass` into a new module `module.submod.utils` that doesn't import anything else from your code and import it from there?

Comment: OK, this seems like a reasonable diagnosis. I moved `CommonClass` to `module.submod.utils` and it looks like everything then works fine. I'd be interested to understand exactly what the cause of the errors are above, but if no-one can provide further insight then I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you execute `from ..common import *`, on the module level or within `TestClass.__init__`?

Comment: `from ..common import *` was called in `test.py` (i.e. the module level)